# How to Merge the Duplicate Values and its Keys present in the HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

map.put("A","1");
map.put("B","2");
map.put("C","2");
map.put("D","1");
```

Expected Output: "AD", "1" and "BC", "2" present inside the newMap which means, if the data values were same it needs combine its keys to have only one data value by combining its keys inside the newMap created how to achieve this in Java?

Comment: It looks as though you should be using "1" and "2" as keys, not the letters

Comment: You can use the `Map.merge` method, but you should probably do this with simple get and put operations as an exercise first.

Comment: Since the `HashMap` is unordered, does your expectation of the keys `"AD"` and `"BC"` imply that you want them *sorted*? Or are `"DA"` and `"CB"` also acceptable? And what if we have `map.put("AB","1"); map.put("A","2"); map.put("BC","2"); map.put("C","1");` as starting point? Concatenating the keys would result in two `"ABC"` keys to be associated with two different values, which is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

You want to group by the "integer" value using `Collectors.groupingBy` and collect the former keys as a new value. By default, grouping yields in `List`. You can further use downstream collector `Collectors.mapping` and another downstream collector `Collectors.reducing` to map and concatenate the individual items (values) as a single String.

```java
Map<String, String> groupedMap = map.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Map.Entry::getValue,
                Collectors.mapping(
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        Collectors.reducing("", (l, r) -> l + r))));
```

> ```
> {1=AD, 2=BC}
> ```

Now, you can switch keys with values for the final result, though I really think you finally need what is already in the `groupedMap` as further processing might cause an error on duplicated keys:

```java
Map<String, String> newMap = groupedMap.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getValue, 
                Map.Entry::getKey));
```

> ```
> {BC=2, AD=1}
> ```

---

It is possible, put it all together using `Collectors.collectingAndThen` (matter of taste):

```java
Map<String, String> newMap = map.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Map.Entry::getValue,
                        Collectors.mapping(
                                Map.Entry::getKey,
                                Collectors.reducing("", (l, r) -> l + r))),
                m -> m.entrySet().stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                Map.Entry::getValue, 
                                Map.Entry::getKey))));
```

Comment: How about using `Collectors.joining()` instead of `Collectors.reducing("", (l, r) -> l + r)`?

Comment: @Holger: Ah, right. I have forgotten it exists. Thanks!

Comment: Note that you solution has flaws (as all others) due to [incomplete task definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74120532/how-to-merge-the-duplicate-values-and-its-keys-present-in-the-hashmap#comment130867546_74120532).

Comment: That's a legit comment, though. I have added a warning to my answer. However, I believe the OP has enough material to achieve whatever they want based on the the answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Java 8**

*You can try the below approach in order to get the desired result.*

**Code:**

```
  public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            Map<String, String> newMap;

            map.put("A","1");
            map.put("B","2");
            map.put("C","2");
            map.put("D","1");

            Map<String, String> tempMap = map.entrySet().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue,
                            Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey,Collectors.joining(""))));

            newMap = tempMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey,(a,b) -> a, LinkedHashMap::new));
            System.out.println(newMap);
        }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{AD=1, BC=2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on logic:

1. Loop through your map
2. For each value, get the corresponding key from the new map (based on the value)
3. If the new map key exists, remove it and put it again with the extra letter at the end
4. If not exists, just put it without any concatenation.

   ```
   for (var entry : map.entrySet()) 
   {
       String newMapKey = getKey(newMap, entry.getValue());
       if (newMapKey != null) 
       {
           newMap.remove(newMapKey);
           newMap.put(newMapKey + entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
           continue;
       }
       newMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
   }
   ```

The extra method:

```
    private static String getKey(HashMap<String, String> map, String value) 
    {
        for (String key : map.keySet())
            if (value.equals(map.get(key)))
                return key;

        return null;
    }
```

`{BC=2, AD=1}`

Comment: This might work for small maps, but is very inefficient.

Comment: @Holger Indeed, but imho, for big maps the creator should consider to change the whole structure by reversing keys <-> values (as positions).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the *keys* of the source map to be concatenated in alphabetical order like in your example `"AD"`, `"BC"` (and not `"DA"` or `"CB"`), then you can ensure that by creating an intermediate map of type `Map<String,List<String>>` associating each distinct value in the source map with a `List` of *keys*. Then sort each list and generate a string from it.

That how it might be implemented:

```
Map<String, String> map = Map.of(
    "A", "1", "B", "2","C", "2","D", "1"
);
    
Map<String, String> newMap = map.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy( // intermediate Map<String, List<String>>
        Map.Entry::getValue,
        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        e -> e.getValue().stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.joining()),
        Map.Entry::getKey
    ));
        
newMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));
```

*Output:*

```
BC -> 2
AD -> 1
```